# Ruby, Prawn PDF Class, each_with_index

Tags: increment, prawn, ruby-on-rails-4.1, ruby-2.1

Ruby 2.1.2
Rails 4.1.1

I have a table in my Prawn PDF class and I have a version that works like this...

```
def rows
  [['ITEM', 'DESCRIPTION']] +
  @rows.map do |row|
    ["", row.description]
  end
end
```

The "ITEMS" field I need to be numbered/ increment by one. So first row is 1, second is 2 etc.

I am trying to use "each_with_index" like so...

```
def rows
  [['ITEM', 'DESCRIPTION']] +
  @rows.each_with_index do |row, index|
    indexvalue = index + 1
    [indexvalue, row.description]
  end
end
```

But I get the following error "data must be a two dimensional array of cellable objects". Am i right to use each_with_index or is there another way I could go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a better way, but here is working code...

```
def rows
  index = 0
  [['ITEM', 'DESCRIPTION']] +
  @rows.map do |row|
    index += 1
    cell_1 = index
    cell_2 = row.description
    [cell_1, cell_2]
  end
end
```

Comment: Post should probably be called "Rails, Prawn, increment table rows" or something. Anyway...